# Dictionary iterator in c#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I want to know if there is any way to store value of an enumerator of key value pairs while iterating through a dictionary.  I want to store the key and value of an enumerator in some variable.  What is the solution?  What I wanted to do is while iterating through dictionary to have a reference of the current key value pair and the next keyvalue pair in the dictionary.I dont know why it is not working

Here is what the solution might look like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WellPuzzle
{

    class Solution
    {
        Hashtable h1 = new Hashtable();
        List<int> listofitemstoremove = new List<int>();

        Dictionary<int, int> d1 = new Dictionary<int, int>();

        public void falling_disks(int[] A, int[] B)
        {
            var itemstoremove = new List<int>();

            var en = d1.GetEnumerator();
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i <= A.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                d1.Add(count++, A[i]);
            }
            //for each incoming element in array
            foreach (int ele in B)
            {
               //store prev as current position of enumerator
                var prev = new KeyValuePair<int, int>();
                prev = en.Current;
                //check if it is possible to iterate to next element in dictionary
                if (en.MoveNext())
                {
                   //loop till end of dictionary
                    while (en.MoveNext())
                    {
                       //if current value of enumerator in dictionary is less than incoming                                                element and check if corroesponding key for that value is in hashtable or not
                        if (en.Current.Value <= ele && !(checkifthatvalueisfilled(en.Current.Key)))
                            continue;
                        else
                        {//if current enumerator value is greater than incoming element from array B then remove all elements from prev reference till end of dictionary
                            h1.Add(en.Current.Key, true);
                            listofitemstoremove.Add(en.Current.Key);
                        }
                        prev = en.Current;
                    }

                    if (!(h1.ContainsKey(en.Current.Key)))
                    {
                        h1.Add(en.Current.Key, true);
                        listofitemstoremove.Add(en.Current.Key);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    h1.Add(prev.Key, true);
                    listofitemstoremove.Add(prev.Key);
                }
                foreach (int item in listofitemstoremove)
                {
                    for (int i = item; i < d1.Count; i++)
                    {
                        d1.Remove(i++);
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(h1.Count);
        }






        public bool checkifthatvalueisfilled(int value)
        {
            if (h1.ContainsValue(h1.ContainsKey(value)) == true)
                return true;
            else return false;
        }
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] A = new int[] { 5, 6, 4, 3, 6, 2, 3 };
            int[] B = new int[] { 2, 3 };
            Solution s1 = new Solution();
            s1.falling_disks(A, B);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code as written? Of course not. You have `en` which is typed to an IEnumerator being used to store a KeyValuePair, and you have `next` trying to store the result of a void returning method. What is it you are actually trying to accomplish? The end, rather than the means.

Comment: It appears your trying to treat a dictionary as something that has an in-order enumerator (or is in order at all). Don't do that. Depending on what you want, have you looked at if a multi-dimensional `int[,]` array will work?

Comment: it looks like you're trying to set the current position of the enumerator, much like you would set a pointer in C++.  If that's what you want, that's not possible in C#; you can only move the enumerator to the next item; you can't just set it to some arbitrary item.

Comment: Or is it that you want to be able to access the previous value of the enumerator as well as the current value?  If so, that's easy enough to do in general, but doesn't make much sense for a dictionary as the sequence has no meaningful order.

Comment: What do you mean by "reference of current location and next reference"? It's really unclear what you're trying to achieve at a higher level.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you want to be able to access the previous value as well as the current value of the sequence.  Here is a simple helper method that takes a sequence and turns it into a sequence of pairs that represents each value with it's previous value in the original sequence:

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<T, T>> GroupAdjacent<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    using (var iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            yield break;
        }
        T previous = iterator.Current;

        while (iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return Tuple.Create(previous, iterator.Current);
        }
    }
}
```

It could then be used like:

```
foreach(var pair in GroupAdjacent(dictionary))
{
    var previous = pair.Item1;
    var current = pair.Item2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a good reason you cannot use:-

```
// Replace TKey and TValue with the types from the dictionary
TKey previousKey;
TValue previousValue;

bool first = true;

foreach(var key in dictionary.Keys)
{
  var value = dictionary[key];

  if (!first)
  {
  ... // Do whatever you need to do with the keys and values
  }

  previousKey = key;
  previousValue = value;
  first = false;
}
```

(Note, though, that you'll likely have to `.OrderBy(...)` your `.Keys` for this to make any sense)

Answer (score 0):

As well as Iain's and the other's approaches, you can also do it like this (like Iain's, this gives previous and current rather than current and next, but they are pretty much the same thing):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Demo
{
    public static class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var d1 = new Dictionary<int, int> {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}};
            bool isFirst = true;
            var previous = new KeyValuePair<int, int>();

            foreach (var current in d1)
            {
                if (!isFirst)
                {
                    // You have current and previous available now.
                    Console.WriteLine("Current = " + current.Value + ", previous = " + previous.Value);
                }

                previous = current;
                isFirst = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here's how you can do it by manually using the enumerator:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    namespace Demo
    {
        public static class Program
        {
            private static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var d1 = new Dictionary<int, int> {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}};
                var iter = d1.GetEnumerator();

                if (iter.MoveNext())
                {
                    var previous = iter.Current;

                    while (iter.MoveNext())
                    {
                        // You have current and previous available now.
                        Console.WriteLine("Current = " + iter.Current.Value + ", previous = " + previous.Value);
                        previous = iter.Current;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need an iterator?  The foreach loop will do that for you.

If you need the current and previous item, you could just store the previous item in every iteration:

```
Dictionary<int, int> d1 = new Dictionary<int, int>();
KeyValuePair<int, int> previous = null;
KeyValuePair<int, int> current = null;
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> item in d1)
{
    previous = current;
    current = item;
    // do what you need to do with previous and current
}
```

You could also use a SortedDictionary, that will give you an index.

Comment: Correct.  If null, you don't have a previous item.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<KeyValuePair<Int32, Int32>> keyValuePairsWithIterations = new List<KeyValuePair<Int32, Int32>>();

foreach(var keyvaluepair in d1)
{
   keyValuePairsWithIterations.Add(keyvaluepair);
}
```

Now you can access your keyvaluepairs by iteration. But it look a little bit strengh... And I still dont understand for what you need it...